# ng serve --open creating problem on vs code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Everytime I type `ng serve --open` on my VS Code terminal and press enter, the terminal cursor freezes and I can't type on it anymore. So I have to restart the app if I want to use the terminal. But if I restart my app then my app on crashes on http://localhost:4200/ and gives the following error message: 'Hmmm… can't reach this pagelocalhost refused to connect.' How can I prevent the first statement from happening? Thanks

Comment: does `ng serve -o` work in the regular terminal?

Comment: @BillF nope, same problem

Comment: @BillF Just realised the terminal shell changes from '1:powershell 'to  '1: node'   Any idea how to change it back?

Comment: Changing from `powershell` to `node` means you're now running a `node` execution. It's like a notification or message to let you know what kind of script you're running using the terminal.

Comment: @Kirubel after the change it wouldn't let me type on the terminal, is that normal for node executions?

Comment: Yes, it's quite normal. You need to wait a couple of minutes. If you included multiple third party libraries in your project, you might face such kinds of issues. Try to create an empty new Angular project and check if the issue exists.

Comment: @Kirubel Oh damn. New windows work fine. I guess I will open everything there then seems like a good solution